# The pop() function does not fully eject the list median

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem description:

```
un_confirmusers = ['A','B','C','D','E']
confirmusers = []
for un_confirmuser in un_confirmusers:
    current_user = un_confirmusers.pop()
    print("The current USER is: " + current_user.title())
    confirmusers.append(current_user)
print(confirmusers)
print(un_confirmusers)
```

Compile the results:

```
The current USER is： E
The current USER is： D
The current USER is： C
['E', 'D', 'C']
['A', 'B']
```

I don't know the pop() not fully eject the list median.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `for-loop` you can use a `while-loop`

**Ex:**

```
un_confirmusers = ['A','B','C','D','E']
confirmusers = []
while un_confirmusers:                      #!Update.
    current_user = un_confirmusers.pop()
    print("The current USER is: " + current_user.title())
    confirmusers.append(current_user)
print(confirmusers)
print(un_confirmusers)
```

**Output:**

```
The current USER is: E
The current USER is: D
The current USER is: C
The current USER is: B
The current USER is: A
['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
[]
```

**Note:** removing elements while iterating over the object is not a good practice.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're mutating the list you're iterating over, so the internal index keeping track of the number of iterations finds itself greater than the length of the list after 3 iterations and ends the loop as a result.

You should iterate over a copy of `un_confirmusers` instead, change:

```
for un_confirmuser in un_confirmusers:
```

to:

```
for un_confirmuser in un_confirmusers[:]:
```

With the change, your code outputs:

```
The current USER is: E
The current USER is: D
The current USER is: C
The current USER is: B
The current USER is: A
['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
[]
```

Comment: Your answer is amazing! THANK YOU.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark the answer you find the most helpful as accepted? (Click on the check mark next to the answer.)